# Laravel Query to Many to many table with optional conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables as follow

dealer

```
 id -  dealer_name
```

specialties

```
id - name
```

dealer_specialty

```
id - dealer_id - specialty_id
```

So Dealer and Speciality model have many to many relation ship so in their models they looks like

Dealer.php

```
 public function specialties()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Specialty');
 }
```

In Speciality.php

```
public function dealers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Dealer');
}
```

Now I have a scenario, where user can filter the result. Like at first whole dealers table will be shown. Now user can filter result with specialties and dealer name. So I have made route with optional parameters. And on my controller I am checking if param ins't empty put a where condition. Its working only with dealer_name as its where condition is referring to its own table. I got problem when I need to put where condition with specialty table.

My code looks like

```
$dealerArray = DB::table('dealers');
if(!empty($speciality )) {
    // how to put where condition like get all dealers with specialit id 4, if this condition matches. I have tried following but its definitely generating error. 
   $dealerArray->specialities()->where('blah blah blah');
   //I have also tried whereHas..
}
if(!empty($keyword)) {
    $dealerArray->where('dealer_name','Like','%'.$keyword.'%');
}

return   $dealerArray->get() ;
```

So finally I want to know how can I put an option condition that If I have to filter dealers from specialty id, how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one 
In the Dealer.php

```
public function specialties()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Speciality::class, 'dealer_specialty', 'dealer_id', 'specialty_id');
}
```

In Speciality.php

```
   public function dealers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Dealer::class, 'dealer_specialty', 'specialty_id', 'dealer_id');
}
```

Query

```
$dealerArray = new Dealer();

    if (!empty($speciality)) {
        // how to put where condition like get all dealers with speciality id 4,
        // if this condition matches. I have tried following but its definitely generating error.

        $dealerArray = $dealerArray->whereHas('specialties', function ($query) use ($speciality) {
            $query->where('specialty_id', $speciality);
        });

        //I have also tried whereHas..
    }

    if (!empty($keyword)) {
        $dealerArray = $dealerArray->where('dealer_name', 'Like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    }
    return $dealerArray->get();
```